# How to get Firestore document ID?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Dart, how do you retrieve the auto-generated ID within a collection's document?

I have a collection called "users" that has auto ID documents with the users details. How do you retrieve that ID?

```
ID eg: yyHYmbDelykMPDWXHJaV
```

[image]

I'm trying to get this id. When the document is first created, when user is first created, the `user.uid` is stored in it's collection.

I can retrieve all the data from the `users` database, which I don't want:

```
  void getData() {
    databaseReference
     .collection('users')
     .getDocuments()
     .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => print('${f.data}'));
   });
  }
```

I can get a future reference for the current user's user.uid but that still doesn't give me the unique document ID.

```
  Future<DocumentReference> getUserDoc() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    DocumentReference ref = 
      _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
    print(ref);
    return ref;
  }
```

Is it possible to search the user.uid against the database users and retrieve the ID that way?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  Could you edit the question to show the code that you're working with, and where you need this ID?

Comment: I need to fetch single documents from the users' collection. Updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the auto generated id, you can just call the `document` method on whatever collection you're trying to get a document from and the returned value will have a getter for `documentID`

```dart
final userDocument = usersCollection.document();
final documentID = userDocument.documentID;
```

You usually do this when you first want to create a document. To retrieve the `documentID` after you've created it, I'd add it to the user document itself:

```dart
userDocument.setData({
  documentID: documentID,
  /* ... */
});
```

Instead of using the auto generated `documentID` though, I personally use the firebase user's `uid` property just because it ties it back to Firebase auth

```dart
// user is a FirebaseUser
final userDocument = usersCollection.document(user.uid);
userDocument.setData({
  uid: user.uid,
  // ...displayName, email, etc.
});
```